# MongoDB Aggregate Group with element name defined by data

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to aggregate the following in Mongo:

```
{"customer_id":1,"attribute":"test1","value":101}
{"customer_id":1,"attribute":"test2","value":102}
{"customer_id":2,"attribute":"test1","value":201}
{"customer_id":2,"attribute":"test2","value":202}
```

to:

```
{
    "customer_id":1,
    "attributes":
    {
        "test1"::101,
        "test2"::102
    }
}
{
    "customer_id":2,
    "attributes":
    {
        "test1"::201,
        "test2"::202
    }
}
```

I've come pretty close using the $group and $push, but that still creates an array instead of the associative array.

```
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$customer_id",
        "attributes": {"$push":{"attribute":"$attribute","value":"$value"}}
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You cannot do this with the aggregation framework if you need the names to be "dynamic". You could specify them explicitly. Your current approach is generally the best approach and you could re-shape the results from the server in code. If you really need this on the server then you can use mapReduce. But that will not be as fast.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected as much. It's similar to a pivot in SQL where values become columns. I could dynamically generate it but there's problems there as well.

Comment: what are you looking for do? Can I have an Example ?